# exception in running on windows7 64 bit

Tags: configuration, installation, sonarqube

When i run sonar using StartSonar.bat i am getting exception like
as i read in http://obscuredclarity.blogspot.in/2012/05/install-sonar-on-windows-as-windows.html and i refered so many documentation regarding this but i did not find the solution for this. And the exception traced is,

```
jvm 1    | Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
jvm 1    |   Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.
jvm 1    |
jvm 1    | 2013-05-06 13:10:25.267:INFO::Logging to org.sonar.application.Filter
edLogger@fee4648 via org.sonar.application.FilteredLogger
jvm 1    | 2013-05-06 13:10:25.301:INFO::jetty-6.1.25
jvm 1    | 2013-05-06 13:10:25.462:INFO::NO JSP Support for /, did not find org.
apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet
jvm 1    | 2013-05-06 13:10:26.451:WARN::Failed startup of context org.mortbay.j
etty.webapp.WebAppContext@70c26b16{/,file:/C:/Program%20Files/sonar-3.5.1/war/so
nar-server}
jvm 1    | org.sonar.api.utils.SonarException: Unable to start database
jvm 1    |      at org.sonar.server.database.EmbeddedDatabase.start(EmbeddedData
base.java:86)
jvm 1    |      at org.sonar.server.database.EmbeddedDatabaseFactory.start(Embed
dedDatabaseFactory.java:41)
jvm 1    |      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
jvm 1    |      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
jvm 1    |      at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Sourc
e)
jvm 1    |      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
jvm 1    |      at org.picocontainer.lifecycle.ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.invok
eMethod(ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.java:110)
jvm 1    |      at org.picocontainer.lifecycle.ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.start
(ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.java:89)
jvm 1    |      at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$Lifecycl
eAdapter.start(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:84)
jvm 1    |      at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.start(AbstractBe
havior.java:169)
jvm 1    |      at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored$RealComponentLifecycle.sta
rt(Stored.java:132)
jvm 1    |      at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.start(Stored.java:110)
jvm 1    |      at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.potentiallyStartAdapte
r(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1009)
jvm 1    |      at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.startAdapters(DefaultP
icoContainer.java:1002)
jvm 1    |      at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.start(DefaultPicoConta
iner.java:760)
jvm 1    |      at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(Com
ponentContainer.java:72)
jvm 1    |      at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform.startDatabaseConnectors(Pl
atform.java:198)
jvm 1    |      at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform.init(Platform.java:138)
jvm 1    |      at org.sonar.server.platform.PlatformLifecycleListener.contextIn
itialized(PlatformLifecycleListener.java:33)
jvm 1    |      at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(Context
Handler.java:548)
jvm 1    |      at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:1
36)
jvm 1    |      at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppCon
text.java:1272)
jvm 1    |      at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandl
er.java:517)
jvm 1    |      at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.
java:489)
jvm 1    |      at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCyc
le.java:50)
jvm 1    |      at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapp
er.java:130)
jvm 1    |      at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:224)
jvm 1    |      at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCyc
le.java:50)
jvm 1    |      at org.sonar.application.JettyEmbedder.start(JettyEmbedder.java:
74)
jvm 1    |      at org.sonar.application.StartServer.main(StartServer.java:49)
jvm 1    |      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
jvm 1    |      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
jvm 1    |      at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Sourc
e)`
jvm 1    |      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
jvm 1    |      at org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp.run(WrapperSimple
App.java:240)
jvm 1    |      at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
jvm 1    | 2013-05-06 13:10:26.473:INFO::Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:
9000
```

may i know where i am going wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some configuration issue related to the database that you want to use for Sonar. Check your configuration in the "conf/sonar.properties" file to make sure that the DB connection properties are correctly set.

Comment: Yes My configuration it self gone wrong. Thanks for your support I am able to run sonar now on port 9000